# Misalignment of R polygon in leaflet map

Tags: r, leaflet, map-projections

When creating a leaflet map from R with `providertiles` the resulting `.html`file  does show a significant misalignment between the polygon (here country borders) and the basemap. Country borders for Switzerland were taken from [here](https://gadm.org/download_country.html) and are projected to EPSG4326. However, the result as shown in the screenshot below (lake Zurich) demonstrates the spatial difference. I am aware of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62817020/misalignment-between-posgar94-polygons-and-wgs84-leaflet-map) and also of [this hint](https://rstudio.github.io/leaflet/projections.html) but they didn't help me any further.

Here is a reproducible example:

```
#set working directory as desired----
wd <- setwd()

#download and unzip shapefile from URL----
temp <- tempfile()
download.file("https://geodata.ucdavis.edu/gadm/gadm4.0/shp/gadm40_CHE_shp.zip",temp)
unzip(temp, list=TRUE)
unzip(temp, "gadm40_CHE_0.cpg")
unzip(temp, "gadm40_CHE_0.dbf")
unzip(temp, "gadm40_CHE_0.prj")
unzip(temp, "gadm40_CHE_0.shp")
unzip(temp, "gadm40_CHE_0.shx")
unzip(temp, "gadm40_CHE_1.cpg")
unzip(temp, "gadm40_CHE_1.dbf")
unzip(temp, "gadm40_CHE_1.prj")
unzip(temp, "gadm40_CHE_1.shp")
unzip(temp, "gadm40_CHE_1.shx")
unlink(temp)

#load polygon (shapefile) as SF----
CH0 <-  sf::st_read(wd, layer="gadm40_CHE_0", stringsAsFactors = F)
sf::st_crs(CH0)
CH1 <-  sf::st_read(wd, layer="gadm40_CHE_1", stringsAsFactors = F)
sf::st_crs(CH1)

#leaflet----
library(dplyr) #for pipes
library(leaflet)
map <- leaflet() %>% 
          addProviderTiles(providers$Esri.WorldTopoMap) %>%
          
          addPolygons(data=CH1, color = "red", weight = 2, smoothFactor = 0.5, opacity = 0.75,
                      fillOpacity = 0.25, fillColor = "transparent", label = CH1$NAME_1) %>%
          addPolygons(data=CH0, color = "purple", weight = 2.5, smoothFactor = 0.5, opacity = 0.75,
                      fillOpacity = 0.25, fillColor = "transparent") %>%
          addMarkers(lng = 8.808369980330726, lat = 47.21968417926996) %>% 

          htmlwidgets::onRender("function() { 
                                    var map = this;
                                    var legends = map.controls._controlsById;
                                    function addActualLegend() {
                                       var sel = $('.leaflet-control-layers-base').find('input[type=\"radio\"]:checked').siblings('span').text().trim();
                                       $.each(map.controls._controlsById, (nm) => map.removeControl(map.controls.get(nm)));
                                       map.addControl(legends[sel]);
                                    }
                                    $('.leaflet-control-layers-base').on('click', addActualLegend);
                                    addActualLegend();
                                 }")
map
```

[image: Screenshot of result]

Comment: It's impossible to answer this without a minimal example. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: @AndrewChisholm: understood. I have added a reproducible example in the main text. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I get the same wrong map if I use mapview in R, QGIS and Google Earth. If I download data for the UK, I can see that maps look correct when compared to OpenStreetMap. It looks to me as though there's something wrong with the Swiss data.

Comment: The data basis of the UK data seems to be from raster data, which however, should not make any difference. Also, UK has not so many borders to verify on level 0 or 1. I tested Austria data and they seem to have the same misalignment. I am not very sure if it is really the data itself.

Comment: I compared Germany to Switzerland using QGIS with Open Street Map only. I can see that the boundaries of the countries are perfectly aligned with each other. In contrast the interior boundaries are correct for Germany but systematically wrong for Switzerland. I suggest using other data for Switzerland.

Comment: thx for that observation! greetings

Comment: I rechecked the legibility of the downloaded boundaries and i can confirm that the geometries from above do not fit at least to the borders of Switzerland. I would recommend to download needed data from here: <https://www.swisstopo.admin.ch/de/geodata/landscape/boundaries3d.html#download>